# How to clean up pulled data from BeautifulSoup, Pandas, Python

Tags: pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hello everyone I have the information I want pulled using `BeautiuflSoup` but I can't seem to get it printed out correctly to send to `pandas` and `excel`.

```
html_f ='''
<li class="list-group-item">
<div>
<div class="tyler-toggle-controller open">
<p class="text-primary">
07/01/2022 Date
<span class="caret"> </span>
</p>
</div>
<div class="tyler-toggle-container row-buff" style="display: block; overflow: hidden;">
<p class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
<span class="text-muted">Comment</span><br>
[1] Comments
</p>
</div>
</div>
</li>'''
```

My code used to pull the data I want:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_f,'html.parser')
for child in soup.findAll('li',class_='list-group-item')[0]:
    print (child.text)
```

Here is the info it pulls But it prints it out weird with tons of spacing

```
        07/01/2022   Date





  Comment
       [1] Comments
```

Ideally, I only need the top portion of (date and File Date) printed out but at the very least I need help getting it into a list format like:

```
07/01/2022 Date
Comment
[1] Comments
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far so good, it's my trying

```
doc='''

<li class="list-group-item">
 <div>
  <div class="tyler-toggle-controller open">
   <p class="text-primary">
    07/01/2022 Date
    <span class="caret">
    </span>
   </p>
  </div>
  <div class="tyler-toggle-container row-buff" style="display: block; overflow: hidden;"> 
   <p class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
    <span class="text-muted">
     Comment
    </span>
    <br/>
    [1] Comments
   </p>
  </div>
 </div>
</li>
'''
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(doc, 'html.parser')

text=[' '.join(child.get_text(strip=True).split(' ')).replace(' DateComment[1]',',') for child in soup.find_all('li',class_='list-group-item')]
print(text)
```

Output:

```
['07/01/2022, Comments']
```

Try this ways,must work

```
text=' '.join([' '.join(child.get_text(strip=True).split(' ')).replace(' DateComment[1]',',') for child in soup.find_all('li',class_='list-group-item')]).strip()
#Or
text= [' '.join(child.get_text(strip=True).split(' ')).replace(' DateComment[1]',',') for child in soup.find_all('li',class_='list-group-item')]
final_text= text[1]+ ',' +text[2]
final_text= text[1]+text[2].split()#if you want to make list
```

Comment: thanks for your help this is what I'm getting when using the same. `['', '07/01/2022  , Comments', '']` its much better any idea on how to get rid of the "" at start and end?

Comment: @seanofdead use    .strip() method

Comment: let me know  whether it works

Comment: I tried `print(text.strip())` I also tried `print(text).strip()`  Attribute error comes back saying list has no attribute to strip.

Comment: I just realized you edited the main answer. Sorry for the delay in seeing that. But the `#or text` works great thank you. but when I print out  `  final_text=text[1]+ , +text[2]`  it prints out 7,/ @F.hoque

Comment: #or text works, great. As I can't test it in live, so it's a bit  hard to explain @seanofdead. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To get your information printed as expected in your question, you could use `stripped_strings` and iterate over its elements:

```
for e in soup.find_all('li',class_='list-group-item'):
    for t in list(e.stripped_strings):
        print(t)
```

**Note:** *In new code use `find_all()` instead of old syntax `findAll()`.*

##### Example

```
html='''
<li class="list-group-item">
 <div>
  <div class="tyler-toggle-controller open">
   <p class="text-primary">
    07/01/2022 Date
    <span class="caret">
    </span>
   </p>
  </div>
  <div class="tyler-toggle-container row-buff" style="display: block; overflow: hidden;"> 
   <p class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
    <span class="text-muted">
     Comment
    </span>
    <br/>
    [1] Comments
   </p>
  </div>
 </div>
</li>
'''
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for e in soup.find_all('li',class_='list-group-item'):
    for t in list(e.stripped_strings):
        print(t)
```

##### Output

```
07/01/2022 Date
Comment
[1] Comments
```

---

Not sure cause you are talking about `pandas`, you also could pick each information, clean it up and append to a list of dicts:

```
data = []
for e in soup.find_all('li',class_='list-group-item'):
    data.append({
        'date': e.p.text.strip().replace(' Date',''),
        'comment': e.select_one('.tyler-toggle-container br').next_sibling.strip()
    })
pd.DataFrame(data)
```

or

```
data = [{
    'date':soup.select_one('li.list-group-item .text-primary').text.strip().replace(' Date',''),
    'comment':soup.select_one('li.list-group-item .tyler-toggle-container br').next_sibling.strip()
}]
```

Output

| date | comment |
| --- | --- |
| 07/01/2022 | [1] Comments |

Comment: I was attempting to get the 2nd part of your answer working with pandas. But when I do `for e in soup.find_all('li',class_='list-group-item')[0]:  data.append` I get object has no attribute 'p'. but when I remove the [0] it works just fine but it prints a lot of info. Im using [0] because this is the list-group-item I want. There are at least 50 other list-group-item

Comment: Okay, it was not that clear - If you like to get only the first `li` slice your `ResultSet` like `for e in soup.find_all('li',class_='list-group-item')[:1]:`  and it will work or use the alternativ option shown in answer that handles exactly this first `li`